# Files deleted from VSCode

Tags: file, delete-file

I have a project using Nuxt 3, when I tried to add it to repository, things got very weird, it deleted lots of files (including package.json, package-lock.json, etc...), added all node_modules folder to stage (even though I had .gitignore properly set). I had 10k+ files in staged area. So basically I was on Explorer tab -> Source Control tab -> initialize repository and all of this hapenned.

I tried to search the missing files in recycle bin, in C:, manually in the project and they simply disappeared. (Can't even check git log because I don't have a repository, all of these files are just flagged to commit).